# How many stationary distributions does the chain admit?

Tags: markov-chains

> Consider the Markov chain whose transition matrix is
>
> $$
> P = \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$
>
> How many stationary distributions does the chain admit?

I did the $\pi P=\pi , \pi=(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$ and found that $\pi_2=0$ so it doesn't admit a stationary distribution? And why?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct but the conclusion you draw from them is not.
Your chain has an infinite family of stationary distributions, all of the form $(p,0,q)$ for arbitrary $p,q\in[0,1]$ for which $p+q=1$.

None of them, as you stated, put any mass on state $2$, which is a "transient state".  The only way the chain can visit state $2$ is if it starts there. If it  starts in  state $2$ it will stay there for finitely many turns and then move to one of the other states, which are both "absorbing".